# Does every block level element have the text-align: left by default?

Tags: html, css

Is it that certain block level elements are only text-aligned to left. What is the reason that by default to have `text-align` set to left for block level elements if that is the case?

Comment: Because left aligned text is the default layout in English? but no, text-align is decided by the browser unless overridden.

Comment: It is the default layout in any language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does every block level element have the text-align: left by default?

`left` is not the default value. text alignment depend on the direction and the direction is by default left to right.

Using a right to left direction will give us a right alignment for text:

```html
<div dir="rtl"> some text here to the right</div>
```

From the specification:

> Initial:   a nameless value that acts as 'left' if 'direction' is 'ltr', 'right' if 'direction' is 'rtl' <sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#alignment-prop)</sup>

---

The [new specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-text-3/#text-align-property) introduces a new value called `start` used as the default one:

> start
>
> Inline-level content is aligned to the start edge of the line box.

You can refer to the following to understand how start is defined: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-writing-modes-3/#abstract-box. You will see that it's also based on the direction

> inline-start
>
> The side from which text of the inline base direction would start. For boxes with a used direction value of ltr, this means the line-left side. For boxes with a used direction value of rtl, this means the line-right side.